# IDP doesn't contain any SingleLogout endpoints

Tags: spring, saml-2.0

When I try the SAML logout, I am getting the below error

> org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: IDP doesn't contain any SingleLogout endpoints
>   org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil.getLogoutBinding(SAMLUtil.java:104)
>   org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl.sendLogoutRequest(SingleLogoutProfileImpl.java:74)
>   org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:138)
>   org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:103)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java

I am using Spring SAML integration

Could any one just tell me the reason for this error. the saml filters are set in the spring xml

```
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
```

and

```
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>
```

are defined

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the idp you are connecting to isn't supporting single logout. The error message says that the idp's metadata isn't advertising single logout support.